# Why does REPEATABLE READ not see new rows?

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

I thought that REPEATABLE READ should not pick up on changed data but should pick up on new data.

However I have the following script:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

create table testLocking(a int);

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    insert into testLocking values (1);
    select * from testLocking;
    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:30';
    select * from testLocking;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;


BEGIN TRANSACTION    
    insert into testLocking values (2);
    UPDATE testLocking SET A=4 WHERE a=1;
    select * from testLocking;
    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:40';
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

drop table testLocking;
```

I get the results:

```
1

1

4
2
```

I was expecting:

```
1

1
**2**

2
4
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

**UPDATED**

I want to be able to see the effects of transaction isolation levels by running queries concurrently.

Comment: Is this running in the same connection?

Comment: It is.  I have to add text here.

Answer (score 0):

Repeatable Read means that changes made by *other* transactions are not reflected in your queries.  You code makes it's change in the same transaction.

**UPDATED**

A single script is not able to show the effects of two transactions interacting with a database.  The best way to do this in SSMS is to separate the code into two windows.  Open them side by side using Window -> New Vertical Tab Group.

By highlighting lines one at a time you can run the transactions concurrently and you will see the effects of the queries in each window.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the row added in the second trasaction and not the first?

Comment: are you running the transactions concurrently in separate windows or are you running the script as written above in one window?

Comment: As above in one window

Comment: ok - then the transactions will run one after the other without influencing each other.  It sounds like you were expecting the second transaction to start after the first transaction hits the WAITFORDELAY?

Comment: Ah ... yes I was.  I tried manually running them from separat windows but that just resulted ih the first query returning 1 each time and the second never returning.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: that depends on what your goal is - if you want to read uncommitted data then this is the wrong isolation level to use. Try READ UNCOMMITTED.

Comment: My goal is to create an example for a colleague of READ COMMITTED and READ REPEATED working differently.